# Why the magnificPopup does not show ajax content

Tags: jquery, ajax, web, popup, magnific-popup

I created a simple web page and wanted to show the popup with different page inside that is loaded as a pop up message, basically I wanted to do sth described [here.](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html). I created the simple webpage:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css"> 
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="hi.html" class="ajax-popup-link">Show inline popup</a>

<script src="js/jquery.lazy-load-google-maps.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery 1.7.2+ or Zepto.js 1.0+ -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script>
$('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
  type: 'ajax'
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and later on I created the sample hi.html webpage:

```
<html>
<body>
hello
</body>
</html>
```

and after clicking the link on the first web page - all I see is the greyed out webpage and the white "Loading..." sentence...
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a doctype declaration in the requested file (hi.html).